# python 3.6 BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python, python-3.x, basehttprequesthandler

I'm trying to make a server programer. and the code look like this:

```
class ALNHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
prefix = r'/Users/huxx/PycharmProjects/ServerDemo'
# handle GET command
def do_GET(self):
    rootdir = ALNHTTPRequestHandler.prefix  # file location
    try:
        if self.path.endswith('.html'):
            finalPath = rootdir + self.path
            with open(finalPath, 'rb') as f:
                print('open successed')
            # send code 200 response
                self.send_response(200)
            # send header first
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text-html')
                self.end_headers()
            # send file content to client
                a = f.read()
                self.wfile.write(a)
                # self.wfile.write(f.read())
                return

    except IOError:
        print('well not found')
        self.send_error(404, 'file not foundbbbb')
def run():
    print('http server is starting...')
    server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8011)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address,ALNHTTPRequestHandler)
    print('http server is running...')
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

the problem is if I use self.wfile.write(f.read()) rather than self.wfile.write(a), there's no response at all.  Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to how the `read()` method works. First, let's focus on this line:

```
self.wfile.write(f.read())
```

`read()` basically reads through your file-like object (`f`) and after finishing this method's call the pointer stays at the end of the memory address. You can imagine it as a "read-once" action for the file. After that, the `write()` call starts and has nothing to write (as the pointer is at the end), therefore there seems to be no response. Now let's have a look at the alternative:

```
a = f.read()
self.wfile.write(a)
```

In this case you read the data from `f.read()` to memory and it stays as a string in a variable `a`. You can read this variable later as many times as you want (unless you delete it) and this is exactly what subsequent `write()` call does.